# Handling csv file in html/javascript file in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, csv

I have a very basic form, in django :

## forms.py

```
class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    fields=forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('Daily','Daily'), ('Weekly','Weekly'), ('Monthly','Monthly'), ('Yearly', 'Yearly'), ('Max','Max')])
```

Response is generated that way :

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    device = Device.objects.get(id=id) 
    device_entries = DeviceEntry.objects.filter(device_id=device) 

    datetimes = device_entries.values('datetime')
    battery_values = device_entries.values('battery')

    writer = csv.writer(response)

    writer.writerow(['Date', 'Battery level'])
    for i in range(0, len(datetimes)): 
        row = []
        date= json.dumps(datetimes[i])
        date = json.loads(date)
        date = date['datetime']
        date = date.encode("utf-8")
        old_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
        new_format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
        date = dt.strptime(date, old_format).strftime(new_format)
        row.append(date)

        #getting the batteries
        batt = json.dumps(battery_values[i])
        batt= json.loads(batt)
        batt = batt['battery']
        row.append(batt)

        writer.writerow(row)



    return response
```

I also have my views.py that returns a csv file (called response)

```
return render(request, 'someFile.html', {"form": form, "response": response})
```

The response, which is the csv, looks like this when i print it, which looks fine.

```
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"

Date,Battery level
2016/08/04 10:14:55,1
2016/08/04 10:14:56,2
2016/08/04 10:14:57,3
2016/08/04 10:14:59,4
2016/08/04 10:15:01,5
```

Now in my html I can do {{ response }} and it is there. However, I keep getting an error : This line `Content-Type: text/csv` leads to the following error `unexpected token :`

What am i supposed to do to handle this csv file, should i parse it some way? If so how ?

The goal is to ultimately pass this csv file into my javascript to create a chart such as

```
g2 = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("battery_historical_linechart"), response);
```

Comment: Should  that be ```g2 = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("battery_historical_linechart"), "{{ response|safe }}" );
```

Comment: @luke_aus That very possible! However that is not my question. For now i am just trying to avoid the error `unexpected token : `. For now when i do {{ response }} in my html, that is the error that pops up.

Comment: try it with '{{ response|safe}}'

Comment: @ luke_aus : i've tried, unfortunately i still have the same issue

Comment: how are you generating 'response' - can you add that code

Comment: @luke_aus: thanks for your help ! Added.